# Process to use NFC tags for identification

Tags: nfc

I bought some NFC tags off amazon and I want to do some project with it. The basic idea is to identify a member by the unique id of the tag. Put it on Google Sheets Worksheet

Tap NFC -> Read ID -> Put on Google Sheet

What is the best way to do this? I’m pretty naive.

Please help!
Siva.

Comment: Hopefully the level of security you require for identification is at the None Level? as using just the ID is very insecure. But without some basic idea of what hardware you expect to do the scanning with it is difficult to answer.

Comment: Hi @Andrew! I do not need any security at this moment. I could start with a Raspberry Pi for this purpose if it is something good to start with. Please suggest :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.